# Codesign software still gives a warning on Windows 10

Tags: code-signing, codesign

I codesign my installation software with a good certificate. I just noticed the current version of Windows 10 shows the warning message below. This did not appear in previous versions of Windows 10. How do I prevent this warning from popping up?

Windows protected your PC

Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a standard code signing certificate, some time will be needed for your application to build trust. Microsoft affirms that an Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificate allows to skip this period of trust building.  [According to Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/), extended validation certificates allow the developer to immediately establish reputation with SmartScreen. Otherwise, the users will see a warning like "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.", with the two buttons: "Run anyway" and "Don't run".

[Another Microsoft resource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/01/09/windows-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-from-running-running-this-app-might-put-your-pc-at-risk/) states the following (quote): "Although not required, programs signed by an EV code signing certificate can immediately establish reputation with SmartScreen reputation services even if no prior reputation exists for that file or publisher. EV code signing certificates also have a unique identifier which makes it easier to maintain reputation across certificate renewals."

If your certificate is non-EV, it is a signed application (e.g. an `.msi` file) that builds trust over time, not the certificate. For example, the certificate can be issued several months ago and used to sign many files, but with each signed file that you publish, it can take a few days for the SmartScreen to stop complaining about that file *after* you publish it. We had such an issue with SmartScreen just once, near the middle of the validity period of our code signing certificate (non-EV), when we released a new, usual beta version of our program. The users wrote about the problem on June 29, 2018, and the certificate was valid from June 16, 2016 to July 17, 2019. We were releasing beta versions frequently before and after June 29, 2018, but it was the only case when SmartScreen complained. It did not complain before or after that.

You question was how to prevent this warning from popping up. To eliminate this warning entirely, i.e. to prevent it from popping up, you need to use an  Extended Validation (EV) code signing certificate.

Comment: Now we need to pay for everything, Do you know how long it's going to be necessary until a standard code signing certificate develops trust?

Comment: @DavidCastro - it is a signed application (e.g. an `.msi` file) that builds trust, not the certificate. We had an issue just once, at near middle of the validity period of our code signing certificate (non-EV). The users wrote about the problem on June 29, 2018, and  the certificate was valid from June 16, 2016 to July 17, 2019. Here is the complaint: https://www.mail-archive.com/tbbeta@thebat.dutaint.com/msg110478.html It took about 3 days until the Smartscreen stopped complaining about the MSI, so it took 3 days for the MSI to build trust, since we published that MSI to the users.