# how many downloads required to build trust using standard code signing certificate

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I'm using the standard code signing certificate for signing our windows applications, but I'm still getting the "unrecognized app" message
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4R4v.png)

then i read that

> If you have a standard code signing certificate, some time will be needed for your application to build trust. Microsoft affirms that an Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificate allows to skip this period of trust building.

from here [Codesign software still gives a warning on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956108/codesign-software-still-gives-a-warning-on-windows-10)

I want to know that how may downloads or how much time is required to build trust using standard code signing certificate?

Comment: Hrm. i am not sure they would release that sort of information publicly, and even if you did know it, it could change. There also might be any sort of heuristic checks as well. I think the idea is they just want you to buy the EV certificate which would have a higher chain of trust :/

Answer (score 1):

The number of downloads or days until the SmartScreen may stop complaining about a software signed by a standard code signing certificate is not specified by Microsoft. We've only had this problem with SmartScreen once, and about halfway through the validity period of our standard code signing certificate, we released a new beta version of our program. The users posted about the issue on June 29, 2018, and the certificate was valid from June 16, 2016, to July 17, 2019. We did release betas often, but this is the only case where SmartScreen has complained. It has never complained before or since. The issue vanished within a day of June 29, 2018. The users downloaded that beta a few hundreds of times on that day until the issue vanished. Hope our experience can give you some references. However, the specific algorithm has not been disclosed by Microsoft, and it is still a mystery. While for us it resolved in one day with less than a thousand downloads, although we did release betas a few times a week, for the other people it took [much more time and much higher number of downloads](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/223505/181264).

We didn't submit our software to [Microsoft malware analysis](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission). Microsoft started to provide this service in 2017.

We also have a few suggestions: all files that can be signed (.exe, .dll) should be signed inside the MSI. If you include binary custom actions into the MSI, these binaries should also be signed.